# ¿Cómo paso de una lista a un data.frame en R?

Tags: r, lista, loops

Buenas, estoy trabajando en R con la siguiente tabla "referrals":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde me describe por usuario la cantidad de visitas que tuvo en cada URL. Mi objetivo es poder obtener para cada usuario, únicamente la URL que más visitas tuvo. Por lo que esperaría obtener el siguiente resultado "out" como data.frame:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilicé es el siguiente:

```
out <- lapply(split(referrals, referrals$USUARIO, drop = TRUE),function(referrals) {
user <- unique(referrals$USUARIO)
ndf<-referrals[referrals$USUARIO==user, ]
idurl <- row.names(ndf[with(ndf, order(-VISITAS)), ][1, ])
besturl <- referrals[idurl, ]
return(besturl)}
)
```

Pero me devuelve una lista y necesito que vuelva a estar como data.frame con el formato "out" que esperaba obtener (mencionado arriba). 
as.data.frame(out) tampoco sirve.

¿Cómo puedo modificar la función para pasar el listado al formato data.frame "out" que espero obtener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
x <- data.frame(User=factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C")),
                Url=factor(c("url1","url2","url3","url1","url2","url3")),
                Visits=c(10,15,5,2,14,20))
result <- merge(aggregate(Visits ~ User, x, FUN = max), x)[c('User', 'Url', 'Visits')]
```

Y el resultado de esto

```
is.data.frame(result)
```

Devuelve

```
TRUE
```

Por tanto, vuelve a ser un `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución alternaiva usando `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  arrange(desc(Visits)) %>%
  distinct(User)
```

Lo que hicimos fue:

1. `arrange`: ordenamos los registros por visitas.
2. `distinct`: Seleccionamos UN registro por User, y dado que ordenamos previamente por visitas, obtenemos el registro con la url más visitada.

Por lo que obtenemos:

```
  User  Url Visits
1    C url3     20
2    A url2     15
3    B url2     14
```